# document provider extension not showing in actions list

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to implement file import to my app through iOS standard sharing  mechanism, something like "Save to DropBox" action. I don't need move option just import. I have read Apple documentation and as I understand it I should use document provider extension (without file provider) to achieve my goal. So I have created a new target in my project with document provider template. But whatever I do I can't seam to get the extension to show itself in share menu. As I understand it, when I open for example Photo app, select a photo, tap on share icon my extension should be there among other actions but it is not. I have tried with different UTIs (including public.image, public.text. public.content, public.data ...), enabling/disabling App groups, iCloud... etc. I am obviously doing something wrong, can somebody please help... Am I on correct path or I misunderstood everything about extensions?
To cut this story short, I want to create the same thing that DropBox does with its "Save to DropBox" action. Thx...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Document provider does not support saving photos from Photo app. You should use Action Extension instead.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Services.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH13-SW1

Comment: yes in the end I came to the same conclusion, I had to look inside the dropbox ipa package to see what they did. Thx for the answer.

Comment: But Dropbox has both a Document Provider and an Action Extension as they show up in both rows.